# iOS NSURLConnection object always returns same response

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, nsurlconnection

I'm creating an iPhone app that consumes a json webservice. I have an NSURLRequest and NSURLConnection object that are used to load JSON data from that webservice:

```
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] 
                                    initWithURL:url 
                                    cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
                                    timeoutInterval:30];
    [request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
    //[request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:YES];
```

```
//create connection
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] 
                               initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
[connection start];
```

First time I executed the above code, using as the url "admin.mydomain.com/param1/value1/param2/value2", the response came through correctly (a JSON string: {"Wrong API Key"}).

I then changed the url to my staging server: "admin.stg.mydomain.com/param1/value1/param2/value2". This server provides me with some completely different output (when I try that new url in a browser, the correct output is shown, a json object completely different from what the first url gives me), but in my iphone app I still get the exact same response I got from the other server. If I try non existent urls I do get a correct error message.

It just seems to have cached the result from the original server and returns the same value for my stg subdomain, somehow matching the two urls (is this possible?), but I have cleared all caching data I could find. I have tried to clean the build and build directory, restarted xcode, the computer and everything, the cache policy is set to ignore the cache (see code). Important: I get the same behavior on my actual iPhone, not just the simulator.

Does anyone have any idea what could cause this kind of behavior? Am I forgetting something obvious?

I have been looking at this for hours on end now, any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried logging your url.description and putting that in your browser?

Comment: what does the full URL creation code look like?

Comment: Could this be a DNS problem or the result of using different virtual hosts? Try to check the two servers in your ios simulator or device browser to make sure that the connection of that device is using the same DNS as your dev environment.

Comment: I have tried logging the url description, the results of putting that in a browser are correct. I create the url like this:
`
//build url
    NSMutableString *urlString = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", baseUrl, action];
    
    for (NSString* key in params) {
        id value = [params objectForKey:key];
        [urlString appendFormat:@"/%@/%@", key, value];
    }
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
`
The dns suggestion I will check out!

Comment: safari on the device and in the simulator give me correct results. DNS seems fine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed the request method to 'GET', now I get the expected results! When checking the url in the browser a get request is used, when posting it I get a different response, which happens to be exactly the same as what I get on the dev server. Problem solved, just have to make some adjustments to the backend to allow a post request!